# I accidently overcharged my iPhone 5c and it stopped working. What should I do?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, charging

For the first time, I left my iPhone 5c charging all night for about 4 hours. In the morning when I unplugged it, it had turned off when it was on when I left it for charging. I tried to turn it on, but the screen won't hitch. At first I thought it got stuck, but it seemed like the battery had been damaged because it won't buzz at all. What should I do?

Comment: It doesn't work this way, You should be able to leave your iPhone plugged in 24/7 without worry.

Comment: How where you charging it? (i.e. what was the cable plugged into).

Comment: This also happened to me today. I left it for like 11 hours and now Im using it and it has no problems like switching out automatically. I guess you're charging your phone and using it at the same time, that's the risk of an iPhone 5c bcoz my iPhone battery bubbled and they changed my battery. So I guess its not about overcharging it, its about charging and using it at the same time. I hope this can help. x

Answer (score 7):

*Theoretically* **overcharging** a device is not possible, as once it reaches the 100% of the battery capacity, it will just stop charging.

Are you sure the device was being charged when you left it? Perhaps you connected the iPhone to the charger but not the charger to the AC?

This will explain why it won't turn on as it would be battery drained.

If this is not the case, going to an **Apple Store** would be the best option.

It's far more likely you just had a failure, unrelated to charging and need service. If it was overcharging, getting a technician to look at it would be even more important that a simple failure, so have it checked out.

Comment: To be clear, OP should also try using a known, working charger on a known, working outlet first to ensure that the device simply is uncharged. Service, though, would be recommended beyond that.